# Does Oracle express 18c have an hr account and scheme as a default?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle18c

Does Oracle XE 18c have an `hr` account as a default?

I know that Oracle XE 11g has an `hr` account with a sample scheme but I can't find an `hr` account and sample scheme in Oracle XE 18c.

So, does Oracle XE 18c have an `hr` account and sample scheme? How can I find it?

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question for this community.  You're asking a "Yes and No" posed question based on "I can't find".  You are expected to conduct exhaustive research. see [How much research is Expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before they post any new questions.

Comment: Did you - by any chance, while searching for it - see this walkthrough? (http://www.rebellionrider.com/how-to-unlock-hr-user-in-oracle-database-18c-by-manish-sharma/) Maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about XE (haven't tried it myself), however, in regular databases you can always install them yourself (see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-1E645D09-F91F-4BA6-A286-57C5EC66321D).

If the scripts are not part of XE, you can download them from GutHub (see previous link).